# Printing in VB.Net/C# Forms Application -- Layout Designer?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, printing

I maintain a vb.net forms application that prints various labels to label printers.  (Label printers are just like any printer, just smaller print area/lower resolution)

The system uses a legacy printing method that's supported in the printer hardware, but has been out of general use for over a decade.  I'm adding logic to print from the PrintDocument class.  I like the flexibility of the class, but layout is a bit tedious.  (Defining the sizes/locations of each DrawString command, etc.)

Are there any software products or open source UI designers for generating print document layout?  The designer output must be something I can integrate into my code (dll is OK, just not a separate executable) and can not have a per user license. (Lots of users on my system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what I need is fairly simple I went ahead and rolled my own simple desinger.  Found at [a great little class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Resize_Control_at_Runtime.aspx)  that makes controls movable/resizable which saved a bunch of time.  Thanks all for the ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this thread [Visual Print Design for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182670/visual-print-design-for-net).

Also, you might consider a PDF template that you can inject with the values, then print the PDF, not perfect, but it could work depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

When I looked for a similar need, I ran across some solutions that were marketed as [business card](http://www.neodynamic.com/Products/ImageDraw-SDK-NET/ImageDraw_SDK_NET.aspx?tabid=95&prodid=8) designers that looked like it'd fit the bill.